# get word before a :- sign in a string with regex

Tags: php, regex, string

I need to get the amount before a :- sign.
So the string would be: bla bla 120:-

And then store only 120 in a variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('!(\d+):-!', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

This should do it. It captures anything up to a whitespace before ":-"

Comment: or \d+ in place of \S+ if you only want to match numbers.

Comment: because he's asking for an "amount" and that would allow for anything (including non-numeric values) before the :-

Comment: Yes I saw it, but not before posting the answer. Corrected it ;) Sorry for the stupid mistake.

Answer (score 3):

The regex

```
/(-?\d+):-/
```

will capture any digits (and a negative sign, if it's there) before a ":-" in the string.

You can than parse that into a number and store it.